# C# Check box, only check the box not the text

Tags: c#, button, checkbox

Okay i swear i looked for this on google before posting.

I tried:

C# check box active area
C# check box check box not text

and a few others.

But i have a check box on top of a button. I want to be able to click the button even when the mouse is over top the check box text area. I want the use to only be able to click the actual box. But when the mouse is over the check box's text, it should click the button.

Thanks all!

Comment: It's very weird behaviour if the click on a checkbox label causes a button to be pressed...

Comment: This is **not** a good idea.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to create that requires overlapping controls like this?

Comment: Overlapping clickable controls is *never* a good idea. User will be thoroughly puzzled and think your UI is bugged.

Comment: try it before you hate it :P its pretty neat and looks really streamline. Granted the button has to be fairly large and the checkboxes text is only one word in length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is in WPF / XAML.

Simply add the checkbox to the button without text.  Add the text to the button not the checkbox.

That said, I cannot for the world think why this would be a pleasant user experience and would suggest trying to use a different means of getting the information.

Comment: Well instead of having a separate section with the three checkboxes, i can just put the three checkboxes on top of the quite large button that way the user will know exactly which button those checkboxes belong to. The checkboxes label will only contain one word so it will actually work and look better then having a separate area with those checkboxes. And this is C# windows forms applications. Thanks all for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

So instead of having the checkboxes over top the button, i just created a seperate window that will show with the three options to choose from upon clicking that button.

But i still think it would be cool/neat to have them on top of the button.